# making the difference between pc to mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with a lot of javascript code in it.
Now of curse the CSS was edited so the website would look good on mobile too.

About js what should I do? Should I just leave everything on the mouse events and keyboard events or should I detect if a mobile device is using the website and then make another file of js just for mobile with the same actions, maybe in the sane file?

I would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: It depends if you have different events for Mobile and PC.

Comment: You won't be getting any mousevents. You my have to use touchevents. The click event still remains

Comment: What events are you using? Generally - this isn't something you should be concerned about - unless there are lots of touch events and swiping and mouseover hovers that are JS specific.

Answer (score -2):

For js it will work hopefully on mobile devices just like it did on your Desktop, you just need to ask yourself if you're using new js code that may no be supported by older browser like for example if you are using `promise`s to make http request then maybe some old phones having old browser will not behave properly (to check if what you are using is supported check this out https://caniuse.com)

Let's say you're using something that is not supported, you can (most of the time) use a polyfill from the internet to make sure the code you write is always working fine.

Comment: So although all the event listeners and all that was coded for desktop, it would work for mobile phones too? So basiclly there is nothing I need to add or change, Its fine the way it is?